# Fetch Firebase RemoteConfig by HTTP API with variables

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I want to fetch an Firebase's RemoteConfig by HTTP API from my CI pipeline and use response as a default remoteconfig built into Android app (default remoteconfig).

I found that I can use endpoint `GET https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/{project=projects/*}/remoteConfig:downloadDefaults`
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest/v1/projects.remoteConfig/downloadDefaults)

Problem is that this endpoint is returning only default values and we are using same RemoteConfig for Android + iOS app and we are using conditions to set different values for the remoteconfig keys.

Example:
Android does have field `foo` set to true and iOS have this field as `false` in remoteconfig. It is configured by built-in conditions feature of remoteconfig.

I also found that I can call:
`GET https://firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/v1/{project=projects/*}/remoteConfig`
To get full version of the remoteconfig together with definition of the conditions.

Is there a way to call endpoint with variables like `app.id`, `app.build`, ..., so I can get correct remoteconfig document for given platform/build/etc?

Comment: *firebaser here* Note that you are calling an undocumented API there. So while it may work, there's no documentation and the API may change at any point.